# Magento get product collection filter by tier price

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, product-collection, tierprice

I want to get all product list who have `tier price`.

**How to filter by tier price?**

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
```

I have tried :

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('tier_price', 'notnull');
```

But it now worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
```

If you are not getting tier price data add it.

```
$collection->addTierPriceData();
```

You can then filter

```
$collection->getSelect()->where('tier_price IS NOT NULL');
```

Comment: thanks but where condition not worked

Comment: try `$collection->getSelect()->where('price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL');`